# Iterate through features to use selection as input for ExtractByMask

Tags: arcpy, cursor, features, extract-by-mask, iteration

I need to iterate through each of the features of a feature class successively to use each one as the mask to extract from a raster with the ExtractByMask tool. Basically I'm looking for the "Iterate Feature Selection" function from ModelBuilder for Python scripting.

If I understand correctly, using a search cursor will return only the row of values from the attribute table, not the feature shape itself.

Would iteratively creating a new shape with "Select_Analysis" be a feasible way to go about this instead?

I suppose creating a new shapefile for each feature would take quite long.

Is there another, more efficient way?

Answer (score 6):

The [SearchCursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) will return geometries with the `SHAPE@` token which can be used as extracting features etc.:

> SHAPE@ —A geometry object for the feature.

```
import arcpy

feature_class = r'C:\test.gdb\polygon'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class,'SHAPE@') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #do something with row[0]
```

You can of course also return field values and use for example to name the outputs. In that case use a list of tokens and fields:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class,['SHAPE@','field1']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #do something
```

`row[0]` will be the geometry and `row[1]` the value of field1

Comment: ok, I think this is very close to what I'm looking for, but when I call the 'SHAPE@' token to define the cursor and then use row[1] as input for the ExtractByPolygon tool I get:
"ERROR 000859: The required parameter Polygon is empty, or is not the type of Multiple Value.
Failed to execute (ExtractByPolygon)."

Using arcpy.Describe(row[1]) and print(desc.dataType) gives me:
"RuntimeError: Object: Describe input value is not valid type"

I suspect that I have to create an actual feature class with row[1] and use that as input for processing. Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: The indexing starts with zero so if you only have the shape token in your cursor you need to use row[0]

Comment: ah sorry, I should have mentioned that, no I have the ID as well, so shape is at 1.

Comment: In your question you are using Extract by Mask, now you say Extract by Polygon. They require different inputs.

Comment: yes, I realized I should use ExtractByPolygon if I want to use a Polygon Feature Class as a mask. But this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I doubt it.  You probably want Extract By Mask and use the polygon as mask.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `ExtractByMask`to iterate over a polygon feature class and batch clip a raster by each feature. In the polygon feature class `grid_id` is the unique name of each feature and is simply an integer that is used for naming the raster outputs. This will save each clipped grid in an `IMAGINE` format though this can be changed by [editing the suffix](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/spatial-analyst/basics/data-formats-supported-by-spatial-analyst.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_560F396561EB4FC5945C28454EA2A8F0). You will need to update the paths in 3 places. Don't for get the trailing `\\` in the first argument of the `outmask.save` function so the last level in the path is recognized as a folder.

```
grid = "path\\to\\grid"    
clip_grid = "path\\to\\polygonFeatureClass"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(clip_grid,['SHAPE@','grid_id']) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        print("Starting Grid Cell " + str(row[1]))
        outmask = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(grid, row[0])
        outmask.save("path\\to\\grid\\folder\\" + str(row[1]) + ".img")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I handled selecting multiple polygons scattered throughout an area that clips from a single raster image(DEM). My area covered four counties, so I had to change the DEM (hardcoded) each time  I ran it. May be a little klunky, but it works. All of my polygons begin with the same naming convention. I use a lot of print statements in my code to verify it's running and that I'm getting the expected outputs. My sanity check....

```
    import arcpy, os
    from arcpy import env
    from arcpy.sa import *
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    env.workspace = "//w63-atlas/Stormwater/Waterways/Structure Flood Severity"
    bslash = "\\"
    Raster = bslash+"\\w63-atlas\Stormwater\AMEC\Platte\TOPO\DEM\platte_dem"
    print " Raster lowkayshunn ",Raster
    tile = raw_input("Enter FEMA TILE : C4, C5, C6, D4, D5, D6, E5, E6, F5, F6, G5, or G6: ")
    outFC = "//w63-atlas/Stormwater/Waterways/Structure Flood Severity"
    prefix = "Export_"
    suffix = "_Culv*_1.shp"
    depiwant = prefix+tile+suffix
    slash = "//"
    aewout = outFC+"/"
    print "aewout = ", aewout
    print "depiwant = ", depiwant
    outFC = outFC+"/"+depiwant
    print "Raster = ",Raster
    print "outFC = ",outFC
    arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "//w63-
    atlas/Stormwater/Waterways/Rasterdatasets.gdb"
    gdb = "//w63-atlas/Stormwater/Waterways/Rasterdatasets.gdb"
    print "gdb = ", gdb
    fcList  = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Export_"+tile+"_Culv*_1.shp")
    print "Shape files to clip from: " , fcList
    arcpy.AddMessage(Raster)
    for i in fcList:
        print "aewout+i ",aewout+i
        print "Shape file: ",i
        Culvnum = i[14:-4] #strip out the name
        rasnew = gdb+"/"+tile+"rz"+Culvnum[:-2]
        print "Culvnum ", Culvnum
        outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(Raster,i) #create temp raster file
        arcpy.AddMessage(outExtractByMask)
        print "Raster image = ",Raster
        print "current Culv = ", i
        print "outExtractByMask = ", outExtractByMask
        outExtractByMask.save(rasnew) # save temp raster to final name
        print "Raster CLip NAMe: ", rasnew
        print "All done creating raster files.  NEXT !!!"
        exit
```