# ArcPy using SearchCursor with Geoprocessing to perform operations on each row

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, geoprocessing, cursor

I have a shapefile, that has lots of individual rows. My goal is simple, to export each row as a raster.
I am trying to use SearchCursor, to select each row and perform a feature to raster conversion. However I am not getting the desired output, so I'm wondering where is a mistake (the tool runs, but creates a nonsense big and all the same rasters)

I didn't find any relevant info on how to combine Cursor with geoprocessing tools.

My code so far...

```
... all the variables, enviroments setting...

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_file, ["FID"]) as tab:
    for count, row in enumerate(tab):
        arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion(input_file, input_field, output_location + str(count) + ".tif", cell_size)
```

I guess this is not the right way to combine cursors with geoprocessing tools. How can I do this?

Comment: Cursors do not tamper with the selection environment, so if you want to iterate the features as *features*, you need to use a Layer and `SelectLayerByAttribute`

Comment: Use oid token in cursor, select by current row oid, feature to raster. Or use modelbuilder with iterator

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297223/arcpy-cursor-runtimeerror-an-invalid-sql-statement-was-used

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this...

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_file, ["FID"]) as tab:
    for row in tab:
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_file, "MyLayer", "\"FID\" = {0}".format(row[0]))
        arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion("MyLayer", input_field, output_location + str(count) + ".tif", cell_size)
```